# Apt-cacher-ng refuses to apt update when offline

Tags: ubuntu, caching, offline, apt

When I use `apt-cacher-ng` as a cache server on my local network and it has internet everything works great. I point my clients (who don't have internet) to the server by adding `Acquire::http { Proxy "http://server_ip:3142"; }` to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy`. The clients can run `apt update` and `apt install <package>` and it works and caches.

If I disconnect my `apt-cacher-ng` server from the internet or put it into offline mode then `apt update` on my clients fails. Because `apt update` fails to run the clients also can not install anything with `apt install`. The server's logs are filled with 500s.

This seemed the easiest way to get an offline install of my application besides mirring Ubuntu but why is `apt-cacher-ng` not able to handle `apt update` without internet or when I enable offline mode?

To replicate on Ubuntu 20.04:

1. `apt-cacher-ng` server has internet
2. Client A (offline) `apt update` on cache server successfully
3. Server no longer has internet
4. Client A can still `apt install` but can't `apt update` anymore
5. Client B (same networking and OS setup as A) can't `apt update` or `apt install`

Answer (score 1):

You can modify configuration file of apt-cacher-ng to consider specific target url content as static or volatile.

By default, Release and InRelease files are volatile, each client update request issues an outgoing request to a repository or a mirror. Turning them to static may achieve what you are looking for but updates, like security updates, won’t be applied to the client OS after that modification.